# Is there any java function to find the sum of the all inputs that user have given?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class civilwar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int irman;
        int captain;
        int sum,sum1;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of total Avengers : ");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){

            System.out.print("\nSelect an Avenger for Ironman's Team : ");
            irman = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("\nSelect an Avenger for Captain's Team : ");
            captain = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Enter the number of total Avengers :
2

Select an Avenger for Ironman's Team : 3

Select an Avenger for Captain's Team : 4

Select an Avenger for Ironman's Team : 2

Select an Avenger for Captain's Team : 5

How to sum the all inputs that mentioned above ?
Is there any java function to sum all the inputs that has been given by user?

Comment: That function is called the `+` operator. As in you do `sum = sum + <somevariable>` with every variable you want to sum up.

Comment: just change `=` to `+=` in the instructions in the loop for example `irman += input.nextInt();`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

No, the Scanner class nor any other I/O Stream class provides a method that automatically converts and internally sums the user input.

You need to manually store your values within an array or a List implementation and then sum them up.